# Generate customer price list

Tags: axapta

I have a requirement for the generation of a full customer by item price list to be exported to a 3rd party program, taking into account trade agreements / discounts etc.

To get the list of customers by items I have tried:

1. creating a double loop (eg outer loop of all customers, inner loop with all items)
2. creating a select statement that joins the custTable to inventTable

To generate a price I have been creating a fake SalesLine for the given customer / item and executing `salesLine.calcLineAmount(1)` in x++

However this takes ~6 hours to process the full customer / item list.

The only other thing I have though of is to run this process once and store in a table, then any time a price / trade agreement / discount is changed, only update the relevant records.

Does anyone have any other suggestions of a better way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 4):

How did you join CustTable to InventTable?  That's just a Cartesian join I believe, which is all possible customers against all possible items, which is inherently slow anyway.

And the nature of pricing/trade agreements/discounts is that they change frequently and it's not really practical to keep a running table of what every price for every customer is, especially if you have trade agreements for date ranges, specific quantity thresholds or units, warehouse it came out of, etc.

Here is code to do what you want and I believe it'd work faster than whatever you're doing.  I quickly wrote this, but it should work and you should remove the integer breaks, I just didn't want it to run forever.

```
static void Job66(Args _args)
{
    PriceDisc       priceDisc;
    container       retVal;
    CustTable       custTable;
    InventTable     inventTable;
    InventTableModule   inventTableModule;
    int             i, n;
    ;

    while select custTable
    {
        i++;

        if (i>5)
            break;

        n = 0;
        while select inventTable
            join inventTableModule
            where inventTableModule.ItemId      == inventTable.ItemId   &&
                  inventTableModule.ModuleType  == ModuleInventPurchSales::Sales
        {
            n++;

            if (n>10)
                break;

            retVal = priceDisc::findItemPriceAgreement(ModuleInventPurchSales::Sales,
                                                       inventTable.ItemId,
                                                       InventDim::findOrCreateBlank(false),
                                                       inventTableModule.UnitId,
                                                       SystemDateGet(),
                                                       1,
                                                       custTable.AccountNum,
                                                       custTable.Currency,
                                                       custTable.PriceGroup);
            info(strfmt("%1 - %2 - %3 - %4 - %5 - %6 - %7 - %8 - %9", custTable.AccountNum,
                                                            custTable.Name,
                                                            inventTable.ItemId,
                                                            inventTable.ItemName,
                                                            conPeek(retVal, 1), // priceDisc.price(),
                                                            conPeek(retVal, 2), // priceDisc.markup(),
                                                            conPeek(retVal, 3), // priceDisc.priceUnit(),
                                                            conPeek(retVal, 4), // priceDisc.deliveryDays(),
                                                            conPeek(retVal, 5))); // priceDisc.calendarDays()];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have tried a variant of your suggestion but it is still way too slow for what the customer wants.

I think this confirms what I suspected, that this is not a viable solution and I need to take a different approach to the whole problem.

Comment: Depending on the # of customers/items you have, it can get astronomical.  Was my method at least any faster?  Also if you pick a subset of items, instead of all items and then choose a consistent pricing scheme, you can do a sync'ing.  If you have prices that are just all over the place though, you might be SOL.

You can also dig into PriceDisc to eliminate redundant code.  If you have no "ALL" or "GROUP" price rules, that's unneeded searches.

Comment: The customer is only using a subset of their customer / inventory list but it still totals just over 1 million records. Ill be honest, I didn't pay that much attention to exactly how long your method took, it was still well over the hour that the customer requested so it is not a viable solution. I think I am going to have to run with exporting the price as it is changed and do the minimum lookup rather than doing a full lookup